I'm trying to import csv data into a Django model. The import is failing due to data types
I'm using the Django import,export module in the admin panel.
The import field in question is a CHAR field. The csv field in question can contain numbers or numbers and letters. If an entry contains just a number, it imports nothing for this field. If I load this csv file in a spreadsheet, it shows that the fields that contain only numbers are considered numbers, but the fields with a mix are obviously not numbers.
No logic, just using import/export in admin.py:
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin   
class Model1(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):


admin.site.register(models.Card, CardAdmin)

I expected the fields with only numbers to be accepted as CHAR, since they are allowed normally. I don't understand why it is not accepting these values as characters, or what I can do about it. Is the problem with the import procedure, how the field is defined in Django, or is it some type of formatting that is needed in the csv? Thanks.

Can you provide a (sample) model that replicates the problem, together with  sample csv, and the exact error message?

@willeM_VanOnsem Certainly. `class Model1(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)set_numberC = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)numberC = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)`
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)

Data (csv): id created_at name numberC
HB1  HB 1
HB1a  HB 1a

There is no error. It simply does not import the numberC data if it is a number, but it does import the data if it is alpanumeric. I don't understand this. Why would it not import numbers into a CHAR field?

Sorry, here is the csv: id,created_at,numberC,name
HB1,,1,HB
HB1a,,1a,HB

[edit] the question. Can you include the logic you use to load the csv file in models?

Why not just add str() around the values being assigned to the model's CharFields? This will either solve or pinpoint the problem.  Also a guess: are any of the numbers floats? 10 and 12 characters are not long enough to store bignum decimal places f.ex 27.6666666667 If so do an explicit formatted conversion.

It's resolved. I'm pretty sure it was the header on the csv, although I thought I checked that. In any case, I appreciate all of the help.
